What dependency should pac4j have with Cas Apereo 6.6.15?
I am trying to configure cas apereo 6.6.15 and I am having problems with the pac4j dependency. For cas 6.6.15 what version of pac4j should be used?
The dependencies I have in build.gradle are:
implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-authentication:${project.'cas.version'}"  
implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow:${project.'cas.version'}"
implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-core:${project.'cas.version'}"

The class I am implementing is:
public class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractPac4jAuthenticationHandler{
...
}

and the error that exists when falling ./gradlew clean build is:
Task :compileJava FAILED
/opt/workspace/cas-overlay-template/src/main/java/support/pac4j/authentication/handler/support/DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential;
^
symbol:   class ClientCredential
location: package org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal
/opt/workspace/cas-overlay-template/src/main/java/support/pac4j/authentication/handler/support/DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.provision.DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner;
^
symbol:   class DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner
location: package org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.provision
/opt/workspace/cas-overlay-template/src/main/java/support/pac4j/authentication/handler/support/DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
private final DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner profileProvisioner;
^
symbol:   class DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner
location: class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler
/opt/workspace/cas-overlay-template/src/main/java/support/pac4j/authentication/handler/support/DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
final DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner profileProvisioner,
^
symbol:   class DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner
location: class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler
/opt/workspace/cas-overlay-template/src/main/java/support/pac4j/authentication/handler/support/DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
protected void preFinalizeAuthenticationHandlerResult(final ClientCredential credentials, final Principal principal, final CommonProfile profile, final BaseClient client) {
^
symbol:   class ClientCredential
location: class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


The post is unreadable. Please use a multi line code format for code, errors and logs.

For CAS v6.6.15, you should use pac4j v5.4.6 (https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/v6.6.15/gradle.properties#L258).

You also need the cas-server-support-pac4j-api dependency from the CAS server.
